# Adverbs that modify verb in an imperative sentence

Tags: adverbs, imperative-sentences

I know of only the following two adverbs that are used before the verb of an imperative sentence;

1. [Always](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/always)

   - Always have your dictionary near at hand.
   - Always be true to yourself.
2. [Never](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/never)

   - Never mind!
   - Never confuse art with life.

Are there any other adverbs that are or can be used before a verb of an imperative sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many adverbs that could be used to begin an imperative sentence. To take just a few examples:

- ***Carefully*** check the ID of all customers.
- ***Kindly*** escort this person to the exit.
- ***Quickly*** go and fetch me some cheese puffs.
- ***Closely*** monitor the situation, and tell me if you see anything

Comment: Most of the examples that I came across contained adverb after the verb and not before it. https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/adjectives-adverbs/adverbs-of-manner

Comment: Yes, in general, I would say that it is more common. But there is nothing wrong or unusual about sentences that begin with adverbs. They will be regularly encountered in everyday speech.

Comment: And "please" too.

Comment: @BillJ According to dictionary.cambridge.org; Please is used as exclamation in imperatives eg: "Please remember to close the windows before you leave."

Comment: @ZeeshanAli No, it's an adverb serving as an adjunct. Never use dictionaries for grammar! However, this one gets it right: [link](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/please).

Comment: @BillJ I also believed that to be the case, but then had to change my mind! Yeah, right, 'please' in my example is, I think, used as adverb.